# Complex derivative and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, complex-numbers

Let $y\in \mathbb{C}^{n\cdot m}$, $a\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $c \in \mathbb{C}^{m}$ three  complex vectors. Let $W\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a complex matrix. I should evaluate the following derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial f(W^*)}{\partial W^*}, \; \mathrm{where} \quad f(W^*) \triangleq y^H \left(\left[W^T a a^H W^* \right] \otimes [c c^H ] \right)y  
$$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. I tried this:

$$
df(W^*) = \mathrm{Tr}\left\lbrace   \left(\left[W^T a a^H d W^* \right] \otimes [c c^H ] \right)y y^H \right\rbrace 
$$
but I don't know how to continue... Any suggestion?

Comment: Are $W$ and $W^*$ considered separate entities?

Comment: Yes, if I well understood, to obtain the "complex derivative" of a real-valued function, we should take the derivative with respect to $W^*$, while considering $W$ as a constant

Comment: At the end of the calculation, the "matrix derivative" should be a matrix of dimension $n \times n$, but I obtained something of dimension $n \cdot m \times n \cdot m$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert
$$
y=\sum_{k=1}^n e_k\otimes y_k
$$
for the segmentation of $y$ into $n$ segments of length $m$. Then
$$
y^H(bb_*^H\otimes cc^H)y 
= \sum_{m,k=1}^n(e_m^Hb)(b_*^He_k)\otimes (y_m^Hc)(c^Hy_k)
=\sum_{m=1}^n(e_m^Hb)(y_m^Hc)\sum_{k=1}^n(b_*^He_k)(c^Hy_k)
$$
So define $Y=\sum_{k=1}^n (c^Hy_k)e_k$ to make the invariant parts more compact to then get
$$
f(W^*)=(Y^Hb)(b_*^HY)=(Y^HW^Ta)(a^HW^*Y)=(Y^HW^Ta)\,{\rm trace}(Ya^HW^*)
$$
giving
$$
\frac{∂f(W^∗)}{∂W^*}=(Y^HW^Ta)Ya^H
$$